# Spring Data not populating model

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am making below get request to `spring` controller but I am getting empty in `itemfilter` bean.

```
http://localhost:8080:/project/api/paytype?cacheBuster=1457063200591&itemfilter=%7B%22name%22:%22Test%22,%22sortlist%22:%5B%7B%22fieldName%22:%22name%22,%22order%22:%22desc%22%7D%5D,%22filterlist%22:%5B%7B%22fieldName%22:%22name%22,%22operator%22:%22a%22,%22value%22:%221%22%7D%5D%7D&page=0&size=20
```

Spring controller method :-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/paytypes", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<Payintype>> getAllPaytypes(Pageable pageable, ItemFilter itemfilter) throws URISyntaxException {}
```

pageable is populating  correctly but i am getting itemfilter object as a empty. Can someone help to solve this problem ?

Comment: @AnchitPancholiCan you post the ItemFilter class as well?

Answer (score 0):

The API url you are using is:

```
http://localhost:8080:/project/api/paytype&cacheBuster=1457063200591&itemfilter=%7B%22name%22:%22Test%22,%22sortlist%22:%5B%7B%22fieldName%22:%22name%22,%22order%22:%22desc%22%7D%5D,%22filterlist%22:%5B%7B%22fieldName%22:%22name%22,%22operator%22:%22a%22,%22value%22:%221%22%7D%5D%7D&page=0&size=20
```

this should be:

```
http://localhost:8080:/project/api/paytype?cacheBuster=1457063200591&itemfilter=%7B%22name%22:%22Test%22,%22sortlist%22:%5B%7B%22fieldName%22:%22name%22,%22order%22:%22desc%22%7D%5D,%22filterlist%22:%5B%7B%22fieldName%22:%22name%22,%22operator%22:%22a%22,%22value%22:%221%22%7D%5D%7D&page=0&size=20
```

You need to use question mark (?) and not ampersand (&) as a separator between url and parameters

Comment: sorry that was typo mistake , but still not getting the data. i tried with ? as well.